# how can i display shopping cart orders on ejs template?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

this is the order schema with cart as an object (session array);

```
var orderSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user :{
       type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User"
     },
    name : {
       type :  String
     },
    phone  : {
       type : String
     },
    residence : {
       type : String
     },
    street :{
       type :  String
     },
    building :{
       type :  String
     },
    status :{
       type :  String
     },
    paymentMode :{
       type :  String
     },
    cart :{
       type : Object
     }
   });
```

and here is the express route which get orders from database;

```
app.get('/api/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res, next) {
  Order.find({user : req.user}, function(err, orders) {
    if (err) return err;
    var cart;
    orders.forEach(function(order) {
     cart =  new Cart(order.cart);
     order.items = cart.generateArray();
   });
   res.render('pages/profile.ejs', {orders : orders});
  });
```

});

Finally the ejs template ;

```
<div class="row">
 <!--Middle Part Start-->
  <div id="content" class="col-sm-12">
    <h1 class="title">Orders</h1>
    <% for(p=0; p<orders.length; p++){ %>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
          <ul class="list-group">
            <% for(i=0; i<items.length; i++){ %>
              <li class="list-group-item">
                <span class=''><%= items[i].name  %>  <%= items[i].qty  %>  <%= items[i].price  %>
                  <%= items[i].price  %></span>
            </li>
            <% } %>

            </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">  </div>
    </div>
  <% } %>

  </div>
```

Looping through the individual orders is giving me headache.

Answer (score 0):

After more research this solved my problem:

```
<div class="row">
  <!--Middle Part Start-->
  <div id="content" class="col-sm-12">
    <h1 class="title">Orders</h1>
    <% for(i=0; i<orders.length; i++){ %>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">

          <ul class="list-group">

            <% for (p in orders[i].cart) { %>
              <li class="list-group-item">
                <span class=''><%= orders[i].cart[p].item.name  %>   quantity:<%= orders[i].cart[p].qty  %>   Unit Price:<%= orders[i].cart[p].item.price  %>
                    Total Price :<%= orders[i].cart[p].price  %></span>
            </li>
          <% } %>

            </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
        <a><span>Status : <span><%= orders[i].status  %> </div>
    </div>
  <% } %>

  </div>
  <!--Middle Part End -->
</div>
```